# Possible to stop copy + pasting into a html textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Got a password field, and ideally we want people to type their password rather than copy and paste it in. Is there an easy way using Javascript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and in my view, it's probably not the best idea.

Comment: I don't see the point here, why is copy/paste for passwords worse than typing it by hand? You only annoy your users with such features. Real threat comes from keyloggers, fake login pages and stuff like that, where it makes no difference if you c&p or enter it manually.

Comment: I think this approach is probably only necessary in extreme scenarios.   Outside of that, blocking paste will interfere with some of the features of some good password management tools (like the very excellent Keepass).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not consistently across all browsers.  Most browsers (not Opera, Firefox 2) support the cancellable *onpaste* event:

```
document.getElementById("password").onpaste = function () { 
    return false;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste

Answer (score 1):

First things first: **this a bad idea**.

You *could* use the key press events on the password field to detect what key was pressed, to check whether the change in the password field matches the event (if they press "a", then check if the letter "a" was indeed inserted), and restore the previous value (with an error message) if it does not.

Of course, people will just have their web browser remember their password for them.

Some banks replace the password field with an image of digits where you have to click to enter the password ([here](http://www.bnpparibas.net/banque/portail/particulier/HomeConnexion?type=homeconnex), for instance). You could use JavaScript to replace the password field with that image when JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':password').bind('paste', function(e) {
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time it takes from the first to the last change. If it was too short, clear the field...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of Polling Technique. Hoewver this is not the suggested way for textboxes. If you have observed some of the Bank site allows you to enter password via a keypad (with mouse clicks). And password field is disabled for keyboard entry